# How do you create a simple reusable library in dotnet core?

Tags: .net, ubuntu, .net-core

I am trying to create a re-usable library in dotnet core using VS Code on Ubuntu.
I can create the library and a set of xUnit tests that successfully exercise it.
So, I did a dotnet pack from the folder that has the project.json file in it like this:

dotnet pack -o /home/me/projects/local-nuget

That worked fine and created my foundation.1.0.0.nupkg file as expected.
(foundation is the name of my library).
The project.json file for my "foundation" library is:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable"
  },
  // This is the references section for this assembly
  "dependencies": {
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

I then created a new project to consume this library called app.
It has a global.json file as follows: (I believe this is how nuget packages are found....)

```
{
    "sources" : [
        "/home/me/projects/local-nuget"
    ]
}
```

It has a project.json file as follows:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "foundation":"1.0.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": ["dnxcore50"]
    }    
  }
}
```

When I do a dotnet restore, I get the following error message:

Errors in /home/me/projects/app/project.json
    Package foundation 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package foundation 1.0.0 supports: net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)
    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
ERROR: Error: Command failed: dotnet restore "/home/me/projects/app/project.json"

The new "app" was created with "dotnet new" and the only change I made was to add the dependencies in the project.json file as shown above.

When I look in my local-nuget folder I see the following:

me@me-desktop:~/projects/local-nuget$ ls

foundation.1.0.0.nupkg  foundation.1.0.0.symbols.nupkg

So, I know that the dotnet pack command worked.

This should not be that hard!  What magic is needed to just create a re-usable library and then consume it in a new app?  We have a lot of source code that we want to move over to dotnet core, but our library structure depends on re-use.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT ====================

Ok, I was also a little suspicious of the global.json file, so I added a NuGet.config at the root of my project.
When I do a dotnet restore, I get the same error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="NuGet official package source" value="https://nuget.org/api/v2/" />
    <add key="LocalSource" value="/home/me/projects/local-nuget" />
  </packageSources>
  <disabledPackageSources />
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

EDIT TWO =============================================
I added a line to my nuget.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="/home/me/projects/packages" />
  </config>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="NuGet official package source" value="https://nuget.org/api/v2/" />
    <add key="LocalSource" value="/home/me/projects/local-nuget" />
  </packageSources>
  <disabledPackageSources />
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

This imported ALL the packages into my "packages" folder including my "foundation" package.  I thought all was well until I did a 
dotnet build.

Now I get an error:

```
 Compiling app for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0                                                                                        
    /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet compile-csc @/home/me/projects/app/obj/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/dotnet-compile.rsp returned Exit Code 1      
    /home/me/projects/app/error CS0006: Metadata file '/home/me/.nuget/packages/foundation/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.6/foundation.dll' could not be found. Compilation failed.
```

When I look in '/home/me/packages/foundation/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.6' I do indeed find the file foundation.dll

However, the error says it is looking for '/home/me/.nuget/packages/foundation/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.6'

Why the extra '/.nuget' node in the directory?  Where do I specify that?

Again, thanks in advance....

EDIT THREE ============================================

Ok, this gets stranger.  I am new to nix, but remembered that hidden files start with a '.' so I looked for hidden files in my home folder and viola, I found the '.nuget' folder.  Chasing down the path, I did indeed eventually find my precious foundation.dll, however it was spelled with a CAPITAL F - Foundation.dll.  I thought that was odd, as I built it with a lower case 'f' but knowing that nix is picky about case, I changed my project.json file to capital 'F' -- 'Foundation' in my dependencies.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Foundation":"1.0.0-*"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": ["dnxcore50"]
    }    
  }
}
```

After doing the dotnet restore, I ventured into dotnet build and was greeted with the following error.

/home/me/projects/app/project.json(8,26): error NU1001: The dependency Foundation >= 1.0.0-* could not be resolved.

So now, I am closer, but still cannot seem to get the equivalent of just adding a reference like I can in VS 2015.

Help please!

Comment: Strange. Have done nuget packages often already on .NET Core. Can you check the nuspec and the folder structure inside your foundation package? The error says the package is only for the .NET Framework (so the classic .NET). The package is a zip.

Comment: You know what, your global.json looks suspicious. The sources directive I have never seen... and I use a NuGet.config next to it for that purpose you use it (check http://json.schemastore.org/global .. there is a packages property). And because, I suspect, NuGet does not get a right feed it maybe feeds you some completely different package??? Like a Windows build from the old days? Try that.

Comment: I added some edits above... This is a brand new Ubuntu box, so there is nothing "hanging around" from before.  I find it odd that the error thinks it is  loading .Net Framework Version 0.0 - this kind of hints to me that it is not finding my local nuget package at all, but I cant figure out what to do to get it to find it.

Comment: Wow. If the capitalization is the error you should file a bug. Try a complete fresh package build with Foundation capitalized from the beginning. It is quite uncommon for .NET to have assemblies with small letter stating.

Comment: Ok, I began to think maybe my library name "Foundation" was somehow confusing the nuget repository - not sure why, just a guess, so I renamed everything TWR.Foundation.  I also changed the version number from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1 everywhere to be sure I wasn't getting something I did not expect.  Well, that did not help, now I get the message: /home/me/projects/app/project.json(8,30): error NU1001: The dependency TWR.Foundation >= 1.0.1-* could not be resolved.  So I basically have the same behavior I had before.  Surely someone out there has this working. HELP